# Is it possible to programatically open a combobox on Form_Show, using mobile framework?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

A friend of mine is trying to open a combobox programmatically right after the form shows.
Actually, i dont know if there's a way to open a combobox that way, because in WinForms, we can use the

```
combobox.DroppedDown = true
```

and the magic is done.

Is there a way to do the same using mobile framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CF doesn't have a Shown event.  You should be able to simulate it by using the form's BeginInvoke() method, like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => comboBox1.DroppedDown = true));
    }
```

Comment: Hans, actually, there is no DroppedDown property on CF. And yep, it could be done on Load event. The only real problem is...it doesn't have any DroppedDown property. Can i simulate it by any other way?

Comment: Sigh, pinvoke SendMessage() to send CB_SHOWDROPDOWN.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations.